# MediaFormat options, the KEY_ROTATION is not work

Tags: rotation, encode, android-mediacodec, android-camera2

The current image is encoded and stored in the output buffer as it is.

However, Samsung (Galaxy S6(Nouga), 7(Nouga), 8(Nouga)) KEY_ROTATION option works well,

This option does not work on the Google reference phone (Pixel 2 XL -> Oreo, Nexus 5 -> Lollipop).

In other words, while the KEY_ROTATION option works well on the Samsung device, the value output to the output buffer is rotated,
This option does not work on Google reference phones.

The surface created by encoderSurface () serves as an input buffer
Check the output buffer through onOutputBufferAvailable of MediaCodec.Callback.

Anyone who knows the reason needs help.

Here is the code I wrote.

```
private final MediaCodec.Callback _mediaCodecCallback = new MediaCodec.Callback() {

    @Override
    public void finalize(){

    }

    @Override
    public void onInputBufferAvailable(@NonNull MediaCodec mediaCodec, int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onOutputBufferAvailable(@NonNull MediaCodec mediaCodec, int i, @NonNull MediaCodec.BufferInfo bufferInfo) {
        ByteBuffer buffer = mediaCodec.getOutputBuffer(i);
        byte[] outData = new byte[bufferInfo.size];
        buffer.get(outData);
        mediaCodec.releaseOutputBuffer(i, false);

        switch (bufferInfo.flags) {
            case MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG:
                if(DEBUG_LOG) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "CONFIG FRAME");
                }
                _configFrame = new byte[bufferInfo.size];
                System.arraycopy(outData, 0, _configFrame, 0, outData.length);
                break;
            case MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_KEY_FRAME:
                // I Frame;

                if(DEBUG_LOG) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "I FRAME" +
                            ", SIZE = " + bufferInfo.size + ", " + currentDateandTime);
                }
                try {
                    _outputFrame.reset();
                    _outputFrame.write(_configFrame);
                    _outputFrame.write(outData);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                break;
            default:
                // P Frame;
                if(DEBUG_LOG) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "P FRAME" +
                            ", SIZE = " + bufferInfo.size);
                }

                break;
        }
    }
```

//

```
    public boolean initialize(int width,int height) {
    try {
        _mediaCodec = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(MIME_TYPE);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    MediaCodecInfo codec = selectCodec(MIME_TYPE);
    if (codec == null) {
        return false;
    }

    MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities cap = codec.getCapabilitiesForType(MIME_TYPE);

    MediaFormat mediaFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(MIME_TYPE, width, height);
    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, 30);
    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatSurface);
    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, bitRateInfo.getInstance().getBitRate()); // 300000
    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 1);

    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_ROTATION, 90);
    // in under API 21, not use MediaFormat.KEY_ROTATION, but use "rotation-degrees"
    // This does not work on a Google reference phone.

    _mediaCodec.configure(mediaFormat, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
    _surface = _mediaCodec.createInputSurface();
    _mediaCodec.setCallback(_mediaCodecCallback);
    _mediaCodec.start();

    Log.d(TAG,"Encoder Start SUCCESS");
    return true;
}

public Surface encoderSurface() {
//Return the value of this function and use it as the input surface.
    return _surface;
}
```

please Help me ..

Comment: did you tried with "rotation-degrees" instead of KEY_ROTATION for Nexus 5 with API 21?

Comment: Yes, but it did not work.

Comment: Are you using the MediaMuxer class? Have you tried setting the orientation hint via `muxer.setOrientationHint()`?